# Best way to store games with a lot of files on HDD

Tags: partitioning, performance, external-hard-drive, exfat

I just installed Age of Mythology on my external hard drive and I notice, that quite a small game (2 GB) occupies almost 55 GB on disk.

[image: Age of Mythology size]

I know, it's due to big allocation unit size, but 1 MB is recommended for 3 TB volume (according to Windows).

```
DISKPART> filesystems

Current File System

  Type                 : exFAT
  Allocation Unit Size : 1024K
  Flags : 00000000

File Systems Supported for Formatting

  Type                 : NTFS (Recommended)
  Allocation Unit Sizes: 4096 (Default), 8192, 16K, 32K, 64K, 128K, 256K, 512K, 1024K, 2048K

  Type                 : exFAT (Default)
  Allocation Unit Sizes: 256K, 512K, 1024K (Default), 2048K, 4096K, 8192K, 16384K, 32768K
```

What should I do in these cases? I like VMware (and other virtualization softwares), that keeps everything in single large file. Is it something similar for games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I like VMware (and other virtualization softwares), that keeps everything in single large file. Is it something similar for games?

Well, it's not the virtualization software itself that is needed here; just its "virtual disk" technology.

If changing the current filesystem is not an option, then you can create a disk image with a *different* filesystem inside it. It will have its own drive letter (by default), and you will have to mount it every time you want to play the game. (You *might* need to reinstall the game, or you might be able to simply move it over... it depends on the game.)

There are third-party tools, but Windows 10 has this feature built in: it lets you create and mount `.vhdx` disk images (the same type that Hyper-V and VirtualPC use) without any third party tools.

1. Create a VHDX image:

   - You can use *Action → Create VHD* in DiskMgmt.msc (if it's grayed out, make sure there's no volume selected in the main list). Once created, it will auto-attach and you will see it in the bottom section.
   - You can use Hyper-V Virtual Machine Manager to create a new VHDX.
   - If you wanted to image an *existing* physical disk, you could use Sysinternals Disk2vhd. But **don't** do it now, because imaging the existing exFAT filesystem will keep the existing bloat problems, too.
2. Note: If heavy writing is expected, "fixed size" images will provide better performance on a HDD due to reduced fragmentation. (Whereas dynamic-sized images will fragment on the underlying HDD *and* on the VHDX layer *and* on the inner filesystem.)

   (This had to get its own number because SU's Markdown parser isn't the best.)
3. Mount (attach) the image:

   - You can double-click the .vhdx file.
   - You can use *Action → Attach VHD* in DiskMgmt.msc (if it's grayed out, make sure there's no volume selected in the main list).
   - You can use `SELECT VDISK` and `ATTACH VDISK` in DISKPART.
4. Partition and format the virtual disk.

   Whichever method was used, it will create a blank image. So fter attaching via DiskMgmt.msc you have to right-click & initialize it, create a partition, format that partition (this time using NTFS – or at least a *smaller* exFAT cluster size). You can do the same via DISKPART if you want.
5. Move the files into the new virtual disk. Make sure the game still works.
6. Detach the image – if you want to.

   - You can use DISKPART or DiskMgmt.msc.
   - You can *Eject* the disk via Windows Explorer (in the Computer window).
7. Whenever you want to play the game, attach the image again.

Comment: Thanks for detailed guide! This is more than I expected and generally interesting not only for gaming.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the format of the disk : exFAT, which is a Microsoft format that was developed for use on small disks, usually in Windows CE.
Its limitation cause it on large disks
to require a very large allocation unit, which causes waste of disk space.

For example, a small text file of 1 KB will take on your disk 1 MB,
which is a real waste.

Therefore I suggest to reformat your disk in NTFS, which is the only
Microsoft format that supports modern large disks.

For the recommended cluster sizes for NTFS, see the Microsoft Support article
[Default cluster size for NTFS, FAT, and exFAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/140365/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat).

The recommended NTFS sector size for a 3 TB disk is only 4 KB.
The absolutely largest size recommended is 64 KB for disks exceeding 128 TB.
Sector size of 1 MB is certainly not recommended.

I suggest then reformatting your external disk as NTFS with sector size of 4 KB.
This will solve your problem without the need for any extra software.

Comment: Is a "cluster" the same as an "allocation unit" in FAT/exFAT? If so, then OP's demonstrated recommendations by the DISKPART tool don't quite match recommendations by the MS knowledge-base...

Comment: @grawity: They are the same. I would go with NTFS since exFAT seems less well adapted for such a large disk (even so the recommended size is only 128 KB but he seems to have lots of small files).

Comment: I think you're confusing exFAT and FAT - exFat is actually newer than NTFS IIRC

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Actually you are right : exFat was the successor of FAT32 and I think is proprietary to Microsoft by patents. It was really designed for Windows CE because the file-system tables are smaller (but also more limited), so is very economical for small disks but not very good for large ones.

Comment: I want to stick with exFat, because of compatibility with OS X..

Comment: Then you should lower the sector size to the minimum possible. Microsoft in my above link recommends 128 KB for 3 TB disk. But it's strange that diskpart only allows 256 KB as minimum. But understand that this is enormous.

Comment: First option with exFat is 256 KB (or at least Windows telling me that), so 55977 files means at least 13,6 GB occupied on disk. If compatibility is not a problem, I would choose NTFS with 4 KB, but in this case I will try virtual disk option.